# Using value of a defined variable in Offset function [VBA]

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to write a code but running into some problems. Here is what I want my code to do:

1. Go to the last cell of a table column (This column always contains integers like 1, 2, 3)
2. Select the value in the cell and subtract 1 from it (if the value in the last cell = 3, then 3-1 = 2)
3. Multiply the result by '-' so we get the same value in negative (eg. -(2) = -2)
4. Now I want to use -2 in the row argument of the offset function and for column argument I will always be using -1 so only the row argument needs to be dynamic

Attaching a sample table for reference.

[image: Sample Table]

What I am trying to do is copy and paste the date next to S. No. 1 then paste it down.

Please help! Also, this is my first question here :) -thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no problem working and calculating with ranges, as you can see from the following example:

```
Sub test()
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A1")
i = r.Value
j = 6 * i ^ 2 - 4
r.Offset(10, j).Value = i + j

End Sub
```

In cell "A1", I have put the value 2 and as a result of my code, cell "U11" now contains 22.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I managed to make it work using tips from your answer :)

Comment: @Here2LearnVBA: glad to see I could help you. In case an answer is useful or contains the solution of your problem, please upvote and/or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is an actual table/ListObject, then you can use `ListObject.DataBodyRange` to help you find the data, for example:

```
Dim dValue As Double
With TargetListObject.DataBodyRange
    dValue = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) 'Last row of last column
End With
dValue = 1 - dValue ' 1-x is the same as -(x-1)
```

Otherwise, you can use `Range.End(..)` to find the last cell in a specified row/column, for example:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count,3).End(xlUp) ' bottommost cell in Column C
```

If you want to avoid VBA, and still find the bottom row: you can count how many non-blank cells there are in a column (`=COUNTA($C:$C)`) — which will give the *wrong result* if there are any blank rows in the column — or use an Array Formula (`{=MAX(ROW($C:$C)*(Len($C:$C)>0))}`, which will work in a `SUMPRODUCT`), and feed the result into an `INDEX` to get the appropriate value:

```
=INDEX($C:$C,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($C:$C)*(Len($C:$C)>0))))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I managed to make it work using tips from your answer :)